# Apache Tomcat (8.5.13) startup issues

Tags: java, tomcat, stderr

I am using Apache Tomcat (8.5.13) with JAVA 8 and MSSQL Database.While trying to bring-up the JVM with all the configuration files (server.xml and context.xml),I couldnt bring the JVM up and running.
    The below mentioned errors has been observed in the Tomcat std err logs.

```
2018-03-16 20:26:01 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:TOMCAT_LOGS\CSX2L\csx2l-stderr.2018-03-16.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:TOMCAT_LOGS\CSX2L\csx2l-stdout.2018-03-16.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

Mar 16, 2018 8:26:19 PM com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.phase2.PRBootstrapImpl 
SEVERE: Error initializing PRAppLoader
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Apache\Tomcat\8.5.13\instances\CSX2L\work\Catalina\localhost\prweb\extractedFiles\apploader\prlog4jcustomappender.jar (Access is denied).

Mar 16, 2018 8:26:19 PM com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega 
SEVERE: Problem during method invocation (contextInitialized)
java.lang.RuntimeException: PRAppLoader was not properly initialized, unable to load class com.pega.pegarules.web.servlet.WebAppLifeCycleListener.

Mar 16, 2018 8:26:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.pega.pegarules.internal.web.servlet.WebAppLifeCycleListenerBoot
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem during method invocation (contextInitialized).

Mar 16, 2018 8:26:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Mar 16, 2018 8:26:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/prweb] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: Did you tried with permission given to your tomcat folder as it’s showing error to access denied to path to you D/Apache/Tomcat/8.5.3/....

Comment: Assuming `...\instances\CSX2L` is the `CATALINE_BASE` folder, delete the content on the `work` folder. It appears you previously ran Tomcat as a different user (e.g. yourself from command-line), and the service user (`System`?) is not authorized to the files there were created then. --- Also, `TOMCAT_LOGS` is probably supposed to be `\Apache\Tomcat\8.5.13\instances`, so fix that in the script you used to create the service entry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your user is not having access rights to the tomcat try to start JVM after giving the access rights for your user and for that ->
Right-click on your tomcat directory then go to properties followed by the security tab and provide access rights.